# Map paging source from Room to domain entities

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

I have model in domain called `ItemEntity` and `ItemRepositoy` which have method to return `PagingSource<Int, ItemEntity>` from database. I also have `ItemRoomEntity` in data layer. In `ItemDao` for this Room entity I have method which is returning `PagingSource<Int, ItemRoomEntity>` from this table.
How can I map `PagingSource<Int, ItemRoomEntity>` to `PagingSource<Int, ItemEntity>`?

Domain

```
data class ItemEntity(val id: Int, val name: String)

interface ItemRepository {
   fun getItemsPaged(): PagingSource<Int, ItemEntity>
}
```

Data

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class ItemRoomEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int, 
    @ColumnInfo val name: String
)

interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM items")
    fun getPaging(): PagingSource<Int, ItemRoomEntity>
}


class ItemRepositoryImpl(
    private val itemDao: ItemDao
) : ItemRepository {
    fun getItemsPaged(): PagingSource<Int, ItemEntity> = 
        itemDao.getPaging()   //How can I map this
}
```

Comment: How are you exposing the paging data to the UI? Android suggests exposing a flow from a Pager instance in the repository layer to the UI layer. Then you can map the flow to your domain entity.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired functionality, your repository should expose a `PagingData<ItemEntity>` rather than a `PagingSource<Int, ItemRoomEntity>`. This adjustment allows for a cleaner architecture by keeping paging logic within the repository layer and not spreading data layer objects to other layers, thus maintaining a clear separation of concerns.

For your domain model to support this, you can include the following dependency, which is pure Kotlin compatible and allows a repository or use case to expose `PagingData`:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.paging:paging-common:3.2.1")
```

Then, within your repository implementation, you should move the logic for creating the `Pager` from the UI or ViewModel layer to the repository itself. Here's how you could implement this:

```kotlin
override fun getFilteredWords(query: String): Flow<PagingData<DictionaryWord>> {
    return Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 100),
        initialKey = null,
        pagingSourceFactory = { dao.filtered1("%$query%") }
    ).flow.map { pagingData ->
        pagingData.map { entity ->
            DictionaryWord(word = entity.word, id = entity.rowid)
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, we're mapping each `entity` to a domain model (`DictionaryWord` in this case). This approach ensures that the data layer objects don't leak into other layers, fostering a cleaner separation of concerns.